# Websocket for Java Embedded suite

Tags: java, websocket, embedded

I want to implement Web-socket support [Oracle Java Embedded Suite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/java-embedded-suite/index.html#docs).

Current Glasfish enterprise server already has support for Web sockets. But I think that including all features of Web socket will add to memory requirements.

Currently I am really confused on how should I implement the same? I am considering only adding support for JSON only to keep memory footprint low.

Can you please guide me on following.

1. Is there custom, faster, low memory foot print implementation of web socket for Java embedded suite.
2. Will JSON only implementation suffice.

Comment: Do you want to implement client for WebSocket for Java Embedded Suite or server?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by JSON only implementation suffice? That depends on the application. I don't think JSON is a low memory footprint compared to a binary protocol, nor it will be less processor intensive, as like an int, you need to do the parsing from text to binary. With a binary protocol you just get the data.

Comment: Who downvoted, as StackOverflow.com suggests, please say why, that can help to improve, otherwise just looks like a JSON fan without facts.